# Error - Please have your activity extend XWalkActivity for shared mode

Tags: android, crosswalk, xwalkview

I am getting the error

> Exception junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Please have your activity extend XWalkActivity for shared mode

in android crash reports. I have not been able to get this crash on testing. I have only used XWalkView in my game and not XWalkActivity. The implementation is as shown below.

```
XWalkView mXWalkView = new XWalkView(context);
MyJavaScriptInterface javaInterface = new MyJavaScriptInterface();
mXWalkView.addJavascriptInterface(javaInterface, "interOps");
mXWalkView.load("javascript:( function () { function createURL(event) { window.interOps.Callback(event.data); }window.addEventListener('message', createURL , false); } ) ()",null);
mXWalkView.load(URL, null);
mXWalkView.setResourceClient(new XWalkResourceClient(mXWalkView) {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadFinished(XWalkView view, String url) 
                    {
                            super.onLoadFinished(view, url);
                    }
});
```

Crash log points to the line

```
XWalkView mXWalkView = new XWalkView(context);
```

And I have integrated crosswalk in **embedded mode** and not **shared mode**; which is why this crash log is confusing. Can anyone help me figure out why this error is being thrown.

Comment: Does your exception also has a stack trace? Could you share it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is from load javascript, i tried to reform the javascript abit:

```
function messageCallback() { window.addEventListener('message', function(event){window.interOps.Callback(event.data);} , false);}messageCallback();
```

dunno it it helps, but couldn't hurt to try.

Comment: I do not think this is the issue as the crash log points to line "XWalkView mXWalkView = new XWalkView(context);"

Comment: Oh ok, yeah I reread the exception, it looks like you need to extend your activity XWalkView, for shared mode. Don´t know what shared mode is though

Comment: But I have integrated xwalk in embedded mode and not shared mode.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you're passing the wrong Context, if you're in the activity class try passing `this` otherwise try `getBaseContext()` or `getApplicationContext()` and see if you get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this;

```
mXwalkView = new XWalkView(this, null);
```

Constructor for Crosswalk runtime.

Public Constructors

```
XWalkView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

Constructor for inflating via XML.

```
XWalkView(Context context, Activity activity)
```

Comment: Yep. I wonder how OP has succeed to compile, because there is not such a constructor mentioned in the [docs](https://crosswalk-project.org/apis/embeddingapidocs/reference/org/xwalk/core/XWalkView.html).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether it is relevant or not. I had same error, i changed supported architectures to v7a and my application runs without errors.